Using pattern and charset together in crunch
I'm using crunch tool in Ubuntu 22.04. It seems that the pattern option (-t) is not respected when used with charset.lst.
For example, I want to generate a list of 4 characters words having only the first letter capitalized and at most two consecutive identical lowercase letters. So I tried to use this command:
crunch 4 4 -f /usr/share/crunch/charset.lst mixalpha -t ,@@@ -d 2@ -o /mnt/hgfs/ZZZ/LIST/out.txt

But my out.txt file contains words like these:
AabV
AabW
AabX
AabY
AabZ
DUXp
DUXq
DUXr
DUXs
DUXt
DUXu
DUXv
DUXw
DUXx
DUXy
DUXz
DUXA
DUXB
DUXC

I would like to get words that respect: upper-lower-lower-lower pattern, possibly using only a set of characters defined by me (I could define a new alias inside the charset.lst file).
Next step will be to change the length of words and add two symbols at the end (so the new pattern will be ,@@@^^) but limited for example to ! And ?, adding them in the custom charset.
How can I fix the problem?

Where man 1 crunch says "lower case characters", "upper case characters", "numbers", and "symbols", it could say "set 1", "set 2", "set 3" and "set 4". The default sets correspond to the terms the manual uses, respectively, but aside from this "lower case characters" is just an abstract "set 1". In this context @ refers to "set 1" and , refers to "set 2".
You can re-define the sets by giving the tool up to four "charset strings" in the command line (example with two strings), or by using -f /path/to/charset.lst and supplying up to four names (aliases) defined in charset.lst. The first string/name will re-define "set 1", the second will re-define "set 2" and so on.
Your command

crunch 4 4 -f /usr/share/crunch/charset.lst mixalpha -t ,@@@ -d 2@ -o /mnt/hgfs/ZZZ/LIST/out.txt


gave just one name (mixalpha), so only "set 1" was re-defined; other sets kept their default values, in particular "set 2" was still "upper case characters".
Your pattern was ,@@@ (in terms of our numbered sets: 2111) and you got strings where the first character was always "upper" (because "set 2" was "upper case characters") but three others were "mixed" (i.e. might be "upper" or "lower", because you re-defined "set 1" as such). The pattern was respected.
To get what you describe as "upper-lower-lower-lower", you don't need to re-define anything. "Set 1" is by default "lower case characters" and "set 2" is by default "upper case characters"; so -t ,@@@ without strings/names should just work.
If you want "upper-lower-lower-lower-custom-custom" then the easiest way is to re-define "set 3" to your custom values, while keeping "set 1" and "set 2" at their defaults. The special string + denotes the default value. Here:
crunch 6 6 + + '!?' -t ,@@@%%

If you add foo = [!?] to the content of /usr/share/crunch/charset.lst then you will be able to get the same result by using -f:
cat /usr/share/crunch/charset.lst - >/tmp/mycharset <<'EOF'
foo = [!?]
EOF
crunch 6 6 -f /tmp/mycharset lalpha ualpha foo -t ,@@@%%

In my tests crunch 3.6 does not work reliably with a non-seekable charset file, so something like { cat …; echo 'foo = [!?]'; } | crunch … -f /dev/stdin … does not work well.
